# How to check a url is working ("Oops, this page doesn't work" - status code 200)

Tags: python, url, python-requests, httprequest

I have a bunch of URLs I need to check and report back whether they are still working or not.

Obviously, the first thing to check is the response status code. If it's 404 you do a couple more rounds to verify it wasn't just a hiccup, and if it stays 404, the url is not working. That's the easy part.

The hard part is status code 200. One would think that if the response status code is 200 the url is working and everything is fine, HOWEVER, a bunch of sites from my list have a strange setting where no matter the text after the domain name, the page displays something along the lines of 'Oops, this page couldn't be found.' while **giving 200** and **not redirecting**.

I tried checking by the response size, since some of these 'Oops' pages are pretty small so they can be differentiated from a trully working URL, however some of the sites have a bunch of clutter on the 'Oops' pages rendering size unreliable.

Also tried checking for keywords such as "incorrect", "bad", "not found" etc., but those are so common, it's practically useless. I'm also getting the titles but again, it seems that every page has their own naming convention for the 'page not found'.

Any ideas on how get more reliable results?

Comment: There are a few Python libraries out there for detecting soft 404 errors like these. I don't know which is considered the best, but a Google search turns up soft404 https://pypi.org/project/soft404/

Comment: Will look into that... Also found this idea: `For each domain/website, you can try an URL which doesn't exists (put a random 512bits string, there's 99% of chance that's will be a 404 error page), and check if pages are the same (with some variations authorized...)`

Comment: That sounds like a clever way of doing it. I suspect some of the Python libs probably try something like that in addition to some natural language processing / keyword detection.